# How to declare a variable that may not exist in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a angular app and I need to use the `chrome` extension object in my app.
So i did in my component:

```
declare var chrome: any;

@Component({
templateUrl: './myComponent.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   ngAfterViewInit(): void {

      if(chrome) 
          //some code
   }

}
```

If im using this code on `Google Chrome browser` it works fine, I do have access to the `chrome` object.

The problem is when Im using other browser like `Firefox`, the console throws an error:

> ReferenceError: chrome is not defined

It seems the typescript does not "declare" the variable chrome if the object does not exist. So I would like to know how to deal with this?

Thanks!

Comment: `declare var chrome` is purely for the compiler; it says *"this will exist at runtime"*. It won't create anything.

Comment: And is there some alternative if the variable may not exist?

Comment: All of the various ways for dealing with `ReferenceError`s in JavaScript - that's what the TS will compile to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration is fine.

The problem is that, when `chrome` does not exist at runtime, you get an exception because the variable in JavaScript does not exist. Do this:

```
if ('chrome' in window) {
    (...)
}
```

instead of

```
if (chrome) {
    (...)
}
```

Then you can use the `chrome` global property, and not have runtime errors when it does not exist